# Automapper: Records constructor arguments error when using IncludeMembers map

Tags: c#, automapper, c#-record-type

We use Automapper 10.1.1 with dotnet 6

Given is the following domain event

```cs
public class EmployeeCreatedDomainEvent : DomainEvent
{
    public Employee Employee { get; }

    public EmployeeCreatedDomainEvent(Employee employee)
    {
        Employee = employee;
    }
}
```

With employee

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

We want to map the domain event to public message contract (record) for the message queue:

```cs
public record EmployeeCreated(int Id, string Name, string FirstName);
```

The mapping looks like this within a `Profile` class:

```cs
CreateMap<EmployeeCreatedDomainEvent, EmployeeCreated>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Employee);
CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeCreated>();
```

When we try to map like that

```cs
mapper.Map<EmployeeCreated>(employeeDomainEvent)
```

We get the following error

> EmployeeCreated needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.

When we try to map like that

```cs
mapper.Map<EmployeeCreated>(employeeDomainEvent.Employee)
```

Everything is fine and works...

**Any idea, why it does not work with `IncludeMembers` and is there any workaround?**

*I know... lazy domain developers who add the domain model to the event... But we can't change it*

The only solution I found so far was to write the record like that

```cs
public record EmployeeCreated
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
}
```

But when we use `records`, we prefer the shorthand constructor variant.

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Same error with MyGet version 10.1.2-alpha.0.4

Comment: My bad, now I see it. `IncludeMembers` doesn't do that. Constructor mapping only considers properties on the source object itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70310695/1811700

Comment: This is now in the MyGet build, but it's somewhat [tricky](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/a311eeb88d8fdff009917ac206b691382d23cee6/src/UnitTests/IMappingExpression/IncludeMembers.cs#L1692) :)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I will test it as soon as the current MyGet Build does not break our build :)