# Automatically map to a subobject in AutoMapper with records

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source object, and a destination object.
The source object is nested in a wrapper object :

```
record Source(string Field1, string Field2);
record Destination(string Field1, string Field2);
record Wrapper(Source Item);
```

So, while mapping I want to unwrap the object, as I don't care about the Wrapper.
Is it possible to create a mapping that would not involve ​mapping each field one by one (the fields really have the same names) ?

Testing and reading documentation, what I found so far is this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Wrapper, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Item);
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

Which works with classes, but not with records : it throws `Destination needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args`
I think I understand why (I guess that the nested object's properties are prefixed with the object's name : `ItemField1`, `ItemField2`, so when it tries to match them with the constructor parameter names, it can't find any match).
I'm not sure if this is should be considered as a bug, or the expected behavior (or an unsupported scenario), but this is quite frustrating.

So, it there another way to do that mapping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Type Converter](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) function to extract the `Source` instance and map this instance to `Destination`:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
cfg.CreateMap<Wrapper, Destination>()
    .ConvertUsing((wrapper, destination, context) =>
        context.Mapper.Map<Destination>(wrapper.Item));
```

Comment: The `IncludeMembers` variant is now in the MyGet build, but it's somewhat [tricky](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/a311eeb88d8fdff009917ac206b691382d23cee6/src/UnitTests/IMappingExpression/IncludeMembers.cs#L1692) :)