# Automapper - Projecting multiple properties from conditionally selected list

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to avoid duplicating the `src.Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusType!.StatusGroupId == 1).OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedUTC).First()` from the below mapping. Without changing the shape of my destinationDto.

I'm aware that I could change the DestinationDto to hold a "StatusDto" object which could then have it's own projection defined, and achieve it that way.

Does automapper have some syntax to do this without having to create extra dto's that reflect the source structure?

Basically a way to say

```
var status = src.Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusType!.StatusGroupId == 1).OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedUTC).First()
```

and then use that status across multiple `.ForCtorParam`

The source looks like this:

```
Source     1 -- 0..N Status
Status     0..N -- 1 StatusType
StatusType 0..N -- 1 StatusGroup
```

```csharp
public class DestinationDto
{
    public DestinationDto(...)

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }
    public string Open { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationProfile : Profile
{
    public DestinationProfile()
    {
        CreateProjection<SourceType, DestinationDto>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ForCtorParam(nameof(DestinationDto.Id), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForCtorParam(nameof(DestinationDto.StatusDate), 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusType!.StatusGroupId == 1).OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedUTC).First().CreatedUTC))
            .ForCtorParam(nameof(DestinationDto.Open), 
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusType!.StatusGroupId == 1).OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedUTC).First().StatusType!.IsOpen))
            .ForCtorParam(nameof(DestinationDto.Status),
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusType!.StatusGroupId == 1).OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedUTC).First().StatusType!.Label))
            .ForCtorParam(nameof(DestinationDto.Created), opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedUTC));

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at typeconverters? https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see a way to use typeconverters to achieve the desired result. A typeconverter could convert Status to something else like string or date, but it's the Where and OrderBy part i want to avoid duplicating

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have looked at IncludeMembers and it does indeed som to be very close to what I want, but I'm not sure how the  `src.Statuses.Where(s => s.StatusType!.StatusGroupId == 1).OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedUTC).First()` would work with that?

Comment: There are many examples in the AM repo and elsewhere online.

Comment: It works with IncludeMembers as long as there is not a constructor and i use ForMember. If i try to do the same with a constructor, ForCtorParam and includeMembers I get "does not have a default constructor (Parameter 'type')". I see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310230/automatically-map-to-a-subobject-in-automapper-with-records/70310695#70310695  that i might have to use `ShouldUseConstructor = c => c.IsPublic;`, but it still fails with a constructor.